# Information inside the div to be displayed when the second radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I have two radio buttons and a div:

```
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test1' />
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test2' />
<div style="display:none">
    Hidden info
</div>
```

What I would like is for the information inside the div to be displayed when the second radio button is clicked, but as soon as they switch to the other radio button I would like it to go away. I would also like to do this in raw JavaScript.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the `click` event on both of the radio buttons, and then use the `checked` property of the one you're interested in to determine the visibiilty of the `div` via its `.style.display` property ("none" for hidden, "" for default [block]).

There are a variety of ways you can access the DOM elements for the radio buttons and `div`. One of the easiest is if you give them `id` values:

```
<input id="rdoTest1" type='radio' name='option' value='test1' />
<input id="rdoTest2" type='radio' name='option' value='test2' /> 
<div id="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Hidden info
</div>
```

Then it's simply ([live example](http://jsbin.com/edemab)):

```
(function() {
    var rdoTest1  = document.getElementById("rdoTest1"),
        rdoTest2  = document.getElementById("rdoTest2"),
        targetDiv = document.getElementById("targetDiv");

    rdoTest1.onclick = rdoTest2.onclick = handleClick;
    function handleClick() {
        targetDiv.style.display = rdoTest2.checked ? "" : "none";
    }
})();
```

Ensure that that script is at the end of the `body` element, or wrap it in a `window.onload` or similar handler.

But if you can't or don't want to use `id` values, there are a lot of other ways to find the elements — getElementsByTagName and then find them by their `name`, etc.

Handy reference material:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) (which now has the HTML-DOM bindings, taking over from DOM2 HTML)

Answer (score 0):

This is straight out of my head, didn't test it but i think it should do the trick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv() {
       var e = document.getElementById('toggle');
       if(e.style.display == 'block') {
          e.style.display = 'none';
       } else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
       }
    }
</script>

<input type='radio' name='option' value='test1' onclick="toggleDiv()" />
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test2' onclick="toggleDiv()" /> 
<div id="toggle" style="display:none">
     Hidden info   
</div>
```

Comment: Since he's tagged this `unobtrusive-javascript`, putting the handlers in the `onclick` attribute is probably not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add and Id to each on the input elements:

```
<input type='radio' name='option' id="option_1" value='test1' />
<input type='radio' name='option' id="option_2" value='test2' /> 
<div style="display:none" id="message">Hidden info</div>
```

With javascript reference each of the radio button, and assign the visibility according to their status:

```
option1 = document.getElementById("option_1");
option2 = document.getElementById("option_2");
message = document.getElementById("message");
option1.onclick = function(){
  message.style.display = "block";
}
option2.onclick = function(){
  message.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: typo : message and not massage in the onClick functions

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventHandler (e) {
    if (! e)
        e = event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement;
}

function handleDivShowing(e) {
    var radio = eventHandler (e);
    var div = document.getElementById('divToShow');

    if(radio.value == 'test2') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test1' onclick="handleDivShowing(event)" />
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test2' onclick="handleDivShowing(event)" /> 
<div id="divToShow" style="display:none">
     Hidden info   
</div>
```

With event handling you have a more generic solution, valid for more than one case.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide()
    {
        var opt2 = document.getElementById("option_2");
        var msg = document.getElementById("message");

        if(opt2.checked)
        {
            msg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            msg.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--The ID is not necessary in the first radio button-->
<input type="radio" name="option" value="test1" id="option_1" onclick="showhide()" />
<input type="radio" name="option" value="test2" id="option_2" onclick="showhide()" /> 
<div style="visibility:hidden;" id="message">Hidden info</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test1' onchange="((this.checked==true)?(document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display='none'):(document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display='block'))" />
<input type='radio' name='option' value='test2' onchange="((this.checked==true)?(document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display='block'):(document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.display='none'))" /> 
<div id="yourdiv" style="display:none">
    Hidden info
</div>
```

It is a little bit long but it works. -- [***> Live Demo <***](http://jsfiddle.net/qSdRm/1/embedded/result/)